# Refresh page 5 times every half second, then append querystring to url using javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write some JavaScript or jQuery that refreshes a page, 5 times only, every 0.5 secs then once that is done append a querystring variable (?refreshed=yes) to the url using javascript or JQuery.

At present I have only been able to refresh once after 0.5 secs and append the ?refreshed=yes querystring. Can someone please point me in the right direction, many thanks in advance for any replies.

```
 <script>
    window.onload = function () {
        if (!window.location.search) {
            setTimeout("window.location+='?refreshed=yes';", 500);
        }
    }
</script>
```

C# code -

```
using LinkChex.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;

namespace LinkChex.Base
{
    public class WebSpider
    {

        const int LIMIT = 10;
        string[] invalidTypes = { ".zip", ".doc", ".css", ".pdf", ".xls", ".txt", ".js", ".ico" };

        public List<LinkModels> Links;
        public bool foundMatch = false;

        public bool IsRunning { get; set; }
        public bool IsDone { get; set; }
        public int totLinks { get; set; }
        public WebSpider()
        {
            this.Links = new List<LinkModels>();
        }
        public void Execute(string url)
        {

            this.Links.Clear();
            this.Links.Add(new LinkModels() { Status = HttpStatusCode.OK, NavigateUrl = url });

            this.IsRunning = true;
            WaitCallback item = delegate(object state) { this.FindLinks((UrlState)state); };
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(item, new UrlState() { Url = url, Level = 0 });
            this.totLinks = Links.Count(); 
        }
        public void FindLinks(UrlState state)
        {
            try
            {
                string html = new WebClient().DownloadString(state.Url);
                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(html, "href[ ]*=[ ]*['|\"][^\"'\r\n]*['|\"]");
                foreach (Match match in matches)
                {
                    string value = match.Value;
                    value = Regex.Replace(value, "(href[ ]*=[ ]*')|(href[ ]*=[ ]*\")", string.Empty);
                    if (value.EndsWith("\"") || value.EndsWith("'"))
                        value = value.Remove(value.Length - 1, 1);
                    if (!Regex.Match(value, @"\((.*)\)").Success)
                    {
                        if (!value.Contains("http:"))
                        {
                            Uri baseUri = new Uri(state.Url);
                            Uri absoluteUri = new Uri(baseUri, value);
                            value = absoluteUri.ToString();
                        }
                        if (this.Links.Exists(x => x.NavigateUrl.Equals(value))) continue;
                        try
                        {
                            bool validLink = true;
                            foreach (string invalidType in invalidTypes)
                            {
                                string v = value.ToLower();
                                if (v.EndsWith(invalidType) || v.Contains(string.Format("{0}?", invalidType)))
                                {
                                    validLink = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (validLink)
                            {
                                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(value);
                                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                                //add the OK link to the List object
                                //COMMENTED TO FILTER OUT OK LINKS
                              //  this.Links.Add(new LinkModels() { Status = response.StatusCode, NavigateUrl = value });
                                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && state.Level < LIMIT)
                                {
                                    WaitCallback item = delegate(object s) { FindLinks((UrlState)s); };
                                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(item, new UrlState() { Url = value, Level = state.Level + 1 });


                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch 
                        {
                            //add the ExpectationFailed link/s to the List object

                            this.Links.Add(new LinkModels(){ Status = HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed, NavigateUrl = value});
                           // this.IsDone = true;
                        }




                    }

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                ///
                /// If downloading times out, just ignore...
                /// 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

controller class -

```
  public WebSpider WebSpider
        {
            get { return (WebSpider)(Session["webSpider"] ?? (Session["webSpider"] = new WebSpider())); }
        }

 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Details(string refreshed, int id = 0)
        {

            LinkModels lm = new LinkModels();
            Domain domain = db.Domains.Find(id);

            if (domain == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            else
            {

            if (!this.WebSpider.IsRunning)
            {
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(domain.DomainDesc);
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    this.WebSpider.Execute(domain.DomainDesc);
            }
            if (!this.WebSpider.IsRunning)
            {
                lm.SpiderRunning = this.WebSpider.IsRunning;

            }

            }
            //remove duplicates from list object
            var distinctList = this.WebSpider.Links.GroupBy(x => x.NavigateUrl)
                                                   .Select(g => g.First())
                                                   .ToList();

            //only send email if page has been refreshed, NOT on initial load
            if (Request["refreshed"] == "yes")
            {
                SendCertificate(domain.UserProfiles.UserName, domain.UserProfiles.UserEmail, domain.DomainDesc, distinctList);
            }

            return View(distinctList);
        }
```

Comment: Refreshing the page is a stateless operation. You lose the current code. You need to append something to the URL (or use a cookie or local storage) so you know how many times you have refreshed before. Alternatively refresh the page using Ajax calls so your code stays in control.

Comment: The question is "why" do you want to refresh the page? You may be solving the wrong problem (also 0.5 seconds is a very short time to allow for a page to load) :)

Comment: I am running a C# script that checks a url for broken links and outputs the returned data via a model to an MVC 4 view, the view has to be reloaded a few times to output a good number of results onto the screen.

Comment: Okay, that just sounds wrong now... Refreshing 5 times to get the results you need from the page is not a great solution. Is there a time delay involved you can just wait for? You really need to provide a lot more information in the question to get an "appropriate" answer.

Comment: To make things a bit more clear I have posted the C# code that does the crawling. I guess I am trying to create a workaround..not good.

Comment: I have written *many* web scrapers, so have to ask *why does the page need to be reloaded at all*? Surely if the page is loaded the links are either there or not there? Is this purely down to the page taking longer than expected to load in the first place?

Comment: Unforunately I do not have the knowledge to create my own scraper so the code is pretty much stock and was taken off an example on the web.

Comment: The example was using webforms, it had a page with a button 'view more' and when the user hit this it displayed additional results that were appended to the list, I have converted to MVC without a button and the page load executing the C# scraper.

Comment: Im going to look into modifying the server code as well, thanks TrueBlueAussie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
var l = document.location, 
    m = l.search.match(/counter=(\d+)/),
    counter = parseInt(m&&m[1]) || 0;
if (counter<5)
   setTimeout(function() {
       l.href = l.origin+l.pathname+"?counter="+(++counter);
   },500);
```

Answer (score 2):

In query string add one more parameter like `refresh=X` and in your function parse this parameter.

The other option is for example use local storage for storing this data.